# Cursor position in the buffer after next-error

Tags: emacs, elisp

After executing next-error from compilation window the cursor is always positioned in the middle of the page.
How is it possible to change the behavior and have the cursor positioned in the 1/3rd mark of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunno why people are advising to advise or redefine `next-error`, or use a hook.  The *doc tells you explicitly* that you can customize option **`next-error-recenter`**, and that its value is passed to `recenter`.

The choices for the option value are:

- No recentering
- Center of window
- A particular line to recenter to

Try customizing this option.

Comment: No problem. FWIW, I know nothing about this. I just looked at the doc for `next-error`.  I even hesitated to mention it, since no one had acknowledged that part of the doc. ;-)

Comment: It seems like you can't set it to "center". If set to `nil`, it doesn't pass the value to `recenter` which then doesn't get that argument telling it to use the "middle" of the window.